# Various usages of needn't

Tags: british-english, auxiliary-verbs

Could anyone possibly simply  tell me which of the following would be correct?

> Tell her she needn't work tonight.
>
> Tell her she doesn't need to work tonight.

Comment: Similar questions:
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26246/neednt-dont-need-to
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116108/are-the-expressions-you-neednt-and-you-dont-need-to-different-in-meaning

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct.

The first is somewhat old fashioned and sounds a bit too formal.

"Tell her she doesn't *have* to work tonight." works too.