# We’ve got plenty of time. We don’t need to/needn’t hurry

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

Do "don’t need to" and "needn’t" mean the same or not? This is a question from an English test:

> We’ve got plenty of time. We ... hurry.
>
> 1. don’t need to
> 2. needn’t

What's the right answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["He needn't say" / "He doesn't need to say".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/99658/he-neednt-say-he-doesnt-need-to-say) Also [Use of needn't in sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128083/use-of-neednt-in-sentences), [The various usages of needn't](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30820/), and probably others.

Comment: Answers you've mentioned seem to say that there's no difference. But I have a test and I have to chose only 1 correct answer. That is what confuses me.

Answer (score 1):

> don't need to = do not need to
>
> needn't = need not

They effectively mean the same thing, so either one is correct. If in doubt, expand all the contractions.

> We do not need to hurry
>
> We need not hurry

the negation is just in front for the first, and behind for the second